# IE does not display border-radius correctly in right to left languages

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, right-to-left

IE is having trouble displaying border radius correctly on some elements when in a right to left language with padding on the parent. The border ends up being offset by what I'm assuming is the padding on the parent. Setting `display:inline-block;` of the element that gets the background seems to fix this, but it causes wrapping issues that I don't want. Here is a fiddle that works in Chrome, but looks bad in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/u3x0twzg/5/

HTML:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <span class="wrapper">
        <span class="border">Here is some text</span>
    </span>
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:grey;
}

.wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.border {
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have a solution for you. Seems that it is a bug in IE. If you make your child span into a p tag it will display properly. Like this.

```
<div dir="rtl">
<span class="wrapper">
    <p class="border">Here is some text</p>
</span>
```

Comment: A paragraph is a block element. I need it to be an inline element.

Comment: I've looked around on line and its a bug in IE the only way I can find around it is to use a p tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for my purposes it has to be an inline element. Using a p tag isn't an acceptable answer, because as I said I know I can make it an inline-block (which is even closer to a good solution), but I can't do that either.